# How to remove all values ​except the largest for given id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table as below. Now I want to delete every row from this table where updatedBy <> 'test'
but while for each test_id I must leave the largest max(version) value.

| id | version | test_id | created_by | updatedBy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | test | test |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | test | test |
| 3 | 3 | 1 | test | test2 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | test | test2 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 | test | test |
| 6 | 2 | 2 | test | test |
| 7 | 3 | 2 | test | test |
| 8 | 4 | 2 | test | test2 |

I can print the largest value for a given id in the following way:

```
select max(version),org_id
from elemHist2
group by org_id
```

However, in delete I cannot use such subqueries because they return more than one value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use subqueries with any statement, you just can't return multiple values from them if you're going to compare the result:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (ID INT, Version INT, Test_ID INT, Created_By VARCHAR(5), UpdatedBy VARCHAR(5));
INSERT INTO @Table (ID, Version, Test_ID, Created_By, UpdatedBy) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 'test', 'test '), (2, 2, 1, 'test', 'test '), (3, 3, 1, 'test', 'test2'),
(4, 4, 1, 'test', 'test2'), (5, 1, 2, 'test', 'test '), (6, 2, 2, 'test', 'test '),
(7, 3, 2, 'test', 'test '), (8, 4, 2, 'test', 'test2');

DELETE t
  FROM @Table t
 WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM @Table WHERE Test_ID = t.Test_ID);

SELECT *
  FROM @Table
```

Here we're just using a correlated subquery to determine the **ID** of the rows we do not want to delete.

| ID | Version | Test_ID | Created_By | UpdatedBy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | test | test2 |
| 8 | 4 | 2 | test | test2 |

You could also use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to exclude the rows that we don't want to delete:

```
DELETE t
  FROM @Table t
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                     SELECT MAX(Version) AS mVersion, Test_ID 
                       FROM @Table 
                      GROUP BY Test_ID
                    ) x
      ON t.Test_ID = x.Test_ID
      AND t.Version = x.mVersion
 WHERE x.Test_ID IS NULL;


SELECT *
  FROM @Table;
```

| ID | Version | Test_ID | Created_By | UpdatedBy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | test | test2 |
| 8 | 4 | 2 | test | test2 |

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach to this using ROW_NUMBER. I used the excellent table variable and data from Patrick Hurst in his answer.

```
with SortedVals as
(
    SELECT *
        , RowNum = row_Number()over(partition by Test_ID order by Version desc)
    FROM @Table
)
delete SortedVals
where RowNum > 1
;

select *
from @Table
```